# How to Run Java Spring MVC on WildFly 10

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc, wildfly, pom.xml

I've developed a Spring MVC 4 application using eclipse neon. After that, I pressed right click to go Run As-> Run on Server and I selected Tomcat server and the web application is working well. But when I do the same operation by selecting Wildfly 10.1.0 server I get Http error 404.

Wildfly web management console is working well.

In POM file I've established the jsp-api and servlet-api dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Wildfly log is as follows:

```
2017-04-08 18:44:18,415 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (External Management Request Threads -- 4) WFLYDR0001: Content added at location C:\Users\Usuario\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\standalone\data\content\c8\74cc39ed9cfeb6494c4908333714c394e43957\content
2017-04-08 18:44:18,436 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "SpringMyBatis-master.war" (runtime-name: "SpringMyBatis-master.war")
2017-04-08 18:44:24,457 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYEE0007: Not installing optional component org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpAsyncRequestControl due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
2017-04-08 18:44:24,458 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYEE0007: Not installing optional component org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
2017-04-08 18:44:24,534 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0005: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (version 5.1)
2017-04-08 18:44:24,536 WARN  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJCA0003: Unable to instantiate driver class "org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jDriver": java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.olap4j.driver.xmla.XmlaOlap4jDriver.<init>()
2017-04-08 18:44:24,577 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0018: Started Driver service with driver-name = SpringMyBatis-master.war_com.mysql.jdbc.Driver_5_1
2017-04-08 18:44:26,494 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Inicializando Mojarra 2.2.13.SP1 20160303-1204 para el contexto '/SpringMyBatis-master'
2017-04-08 18:44:29,665 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: /SpringMyBatis-master
2017-04-08 18:44:29,729 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (External Management Request Threads -- 4) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "SpringMyBatis-master.war" (runtime-name : "SpringMyBatis-master.war")
```

What is it missing in this case? Thanks

Comment: can you share the log file or the error that may be helpful to figure out the issue.

Comment: Ok, I've added the Wildfly log in the question

Comment: suppose the issue is with `XmlaOlap4jDriver` as mentioned in the log. please refer this [link](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/263238)

Comment: It's working over wildfly (more less). I had to create the spring mvc project from scratch with target wildfly by eclipse. Use mysql 5 to avoid xmlolap.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your project . In drop down menu select

properties->Run Time->and select wildfly as target run time .

Press apply

Now run your project .Now deploy your web app and run .It will work

Comment: I did what you recommended but it's not working yet. It turns out Error 404.

Answer (score 0):

Your 2 dependencies should be in scope **provided** instead of **compile** otherwise they end up in your war file and this is incorrect. You should never put Java EE API jars in your applications.